# Rotation of spin orbit coupling matrix

Tags: hamiltonian, rotation, ferromagnetism, spin-orbit

In first-principle calculation, we could get different solutions for different directions of magnetization for ferromagnetic system.

I want to know the details about whether or when does the SOC matrix  $H_{soc}=\lambda \vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_{\uparrow}L_z & \bar{\lambda}L_+ \\ \bar{\lambda}L_- & -\lambda_{\downarrow}L_z \end{pmatrix}$ need to rotate ($UH_{soc}U^{-1}$)when rotating the magnetization?

Comment: What is the operation $U$?

Comment: It is a rotateion operation. My question has been solved. Thank you for your attention!